# Azure CosmosDb Emulator Error: Failed loading emulator secrets certificate. Error 0x8009000f

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm sorry for creating another question about this, as I've seen some here already, but I can't comment and I feel like this is a more common problem as of late.

I've tried all the common troubleshooting steps:

1. Restart computer
2. Open PowerShell and CMD as admin
3. Uninstalled and reinstsalled the emulator

I'm cd'ing into: C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator and running: `.\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /port=8082` and getting the same error every time:

[emulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syncr.png)

I would love to know if anyone else has recently seen this issue or at all before. I'm on Windows 10.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#install-the-emulator), make sure you have the following software and hardware requirements:

**Software requirements:**

- Currently Windows Server 2016, 2019 or Windows 10 host OS are supported. The host OS with Active Directory enabled is currently not supported.
- 64-bit operating system

**Minimum hardware requirements:**

- 2-GB RAM
- 10-GB available hard disk space

•   To install, configure, and run the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, you must have administrative privileges on the computer. The emulator will add a certificate and also set the firewall rules in order to run its services. Therefore admin rights are necessary for the emulator to be able to execute such operations.

Also try after delete of `CosmosEmulatorSecrets` and `DocumentDbEmulatorCertificate` these 2 certificates from certificate manager.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I absolutely should have edited my post as I did find online to make sure I saw the official docs and confirmed my machine is appropriate. So I'm running Windows 10 and have plenty of storage space + 32gb of RAM. I have checked for those 2 certs and cannot find them anywhere. I'm not sure what else to check.